# PHP validating a bunch of check boxes failing

Tags: php

**Form**

```
echo '<form action="formProcess.php" method="post">';
echo    '<input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="US">';
echo    '<input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="UK">';
echo    '<input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="SE">';
echo    '<input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="CA">';
echo    '<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">';
echo '</form>';

?>
```

**formProcess.php**

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['country'])) {
    echo 'Set <br>';
    if (check($_POST['country'])){
        echo 'Country OK<br>';
    } else {
        echo 'Country Faulty<br>';
    }

} else {
    echo 'Not Set';
}

function check($colors) { // This function is where I fail
    global $countries;

    foreach($colors as $country) {
        echo "You selected: $country <br>";
        if (array_key_exists($country,$countries)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

I'm trying to validate a bunch of checkboxes, but I'm going wrong with the `return` part inside the function.

The problem is, even if I select more than one checkbox, i get only one value outputted. The problem is in the `return` in the function. How is this done right?

**Output**

```
Set

You selected: US // Outputs only one even when more are selected.

Country OK
```

**countries array**

```
$countries = array (
"US" => "United States Of America",
"GB" => "United Kingdom",
"CA" => "Canada"
// a lot more removed for this question
}
```

Comment: As a side note, in your initial html form output, instead of typing in `echo` multiple times, you can simply use `echo` on the first string, do not put a `;` after the string, and replace the `echo` on the next line with `,`. This will continue the echo over multiple strings.

Comment: Why are all of your checkboxes named country and why the []?

Comment: Should it be possible to select more then one country?

Comment: @PhilipG Yes. The user can select more than one country.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an array with the selected checkboxes and return that instead.

```
function check($colors) { 
    global $countries;
    $checkedCountries = array();
    foreach($colors as $country) {
        echo "You selected: $country <br>";
        if (array_key_exists($country,$countries)) {
            $checkedCountries[] = $country;
            echo $country . "<br />";
        }
    }
    if(count($checkedCountries) > 0)
    return true;
    else  
    return false;
}
```

Comment: In your answer, is it possible to just have it return true or false without returning the names. If all is ok, i'll simply implode the original array and send it to a DB table. Your current answer works well too.

Comment: changed my answer so that if one checkbox is checked, the function will return true, if none is checked, will return false.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a bit awkward, but:

```
function check($colors) {
    global $countries;

    foreach($colors as $country) {
        echo "You selected: $country <br>";
        if (!array_key_exists($country,$countries)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: this would cause the function to return false if for example the first country is not checked.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the result on the first match itself, since you are looking to display all the checked items, you need rewrite your function like this..

```
<?php
function check($colors) {
    global $countries;

    $cntries=array();
    foreach($colors as $country) {
        if (array_key_exists($country,$countries)) {
            $cntries[]=$country;
        }else { return false;}
    }
    echo $str= "You selected ".implode("<br>",$cntries);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Any chance of just using true or false inside that function without having to output name? If all the names are OK, I'll simply pass them to a DB.

Comment: So you want the function to return true if all the checkboxes are selected , else return false.. right ?

Comment: No. Return false if a value from the form is not found in the countries array. Number of check boxes being checked does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

You will achieve this using the following function

```
function check($colors) { // This function is where I fail
    global $countries;

    foreach($colors as $country) {

        //if country not exists, set return to false;
        if (!array_key_exists($country,$countries)) {
            return false;
        }
        //If you want to echo selected countries
        else{
                   echo "You selected" . $country;
        }
    }
    //If all contries exist, return true.

    return true;
}
```

you can then loop your array outputting the selected countries!

Comment: This returns false all the time.

Comment: how does your $countries array look like?

Comment: I've tested the code now and it is working. If you do var_dump($_POST['country']); whats your return?

Comment: this would cause the function to return false if for example the first country is not checked.

Comment: @VolkanUlukut it would not! i've tested this code and it is working as expected. $_POST['country'] is just populated with the values of the checked checkboxes. Either way it is easy solvable using array_filter().

Comment: @Norman are you sure that $contries is defined before your function call is made?

Comment: Yes it is. It's declared.

Comment: what happens if you var_dump $_POST['country']?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set a variable to false before the loop
2. Set that variable to true inside the loop where you currently return true
3. Get rid of the else entirely
4. Return that variable after the loop